# How to secure JWT token and refresh token in nodejs/angular

Tags: node.js, angularjs

i am new in node js. I am building a simple notes taking app and wanted to use JWT tokens for authentication and to secure my API's. On research i came to know that i need to create two tokens:

1. access token (short expire time like 10 minutes)
2. refresh token (longer expire time 30 days)

My config file

```
"secret": "*************",
"refreshTokenSecret": "*************",
"port": 5000,
"tokenLife": 900,
"refreshTokenLife": 86400
```

Code for middleware

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const config = require('./config')

module.exports = (req,res,next) => {
  const token = req.body.token || req.query.token || req.headers['x-access-token']
  // decode token
  if (token) {
    // verifies secret and checks exp
    jwt.verify(token, config.secret, function(err, decoded) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(401).json({"error": true, "message": 'Unauthorized access.' });
        }
      req.decoded = decoded;
      next();
    });
  } else {
    // if there is no token
    // return an error
    return res.status(403).send({
        "error": true,
        "message": 'No token provided.'
    });
  }
}
```

Here is the response

[image]

access token can be saved in local storage. but articles said save refresh token as http-only cookie.
i need the answer of following points (Keeping in mind that i am just a beginner):

1. How to store refresh token as http-only cookie (any node-js code
   example would be a great help)?
2. How to secure it on client side and should I save refresh token to database?
3. Is there any other better solution to secure my API's?

Comment: check these two npm packages: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken, https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-jwt

Comment: @SébastienB i know how to use and generate token. I just wanted to know how to make them secure

Comment: What do you mean by secure them? with the packages I mentioned you can use a private and public RSA keys to sign and read the tokens and you don't need to store them in any DB, for the client side it will depend of the platform (mobile app, web app, browser..) just use the best available way to store a token of the platform. And I'll recommend you to be consistent with the way you are sending the token to your API, for example only allow to send it in the headers with the key `Authorization`

Comment: Its a web app. Can you give any example of Authorization headers

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization and in your API you will have a middleware with: `res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, content-type, Authorization");`

Comment: JWT aren't really great for securing an application. For simple use cases they are fine, but for instance (as mentioned below) there is no way to revoke access from a JWT unless it's stored in a database, at which point you're better off using a more robust authentication strategy. If you have the time, look into using passport http://www.passportjs.org/ it's not required/ the only way to do authentication, but it's a great jumping off point on this wide world of app security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an http-only cookie using the following:

```
public authenticateUser(user: User, res: Response) {
        const authJwtToken = this.generateJWT({
            email: user.email,
            uuid: user.uuid
        });

        const cookieOptions = {
            maxAge: 3600000,
            secure: true,
            httpOnly: true
        };

        res.cookie('access_token', authJwtToken, cookieOptions);
    }
// you can then res.send({...}) or wtv
```

Not that there is nothing from preventing you to store more than one cookie so I can't see a reason why not storing both of them in the same manner.

Now whether you will store it on the database depends on what you want to achieve. 
Generally it is not required but note that in that case the server cannot in any way invalidate a single JWT. (You could in theory change the signing key but this would invalidate all of them).

In case you want to be able to achieve functionality such as 'log me out of all devices' you would need to store the JWTs issued for each user in a database (preferably an in-memory one such as Redis or Memcached) and do a second check with the extra information on whether they have been invalidated or not - even though such functionality is typically achieved using sessions instead of JWT

Comment: Is it secure? as anyone can get refresh token and generate new access token. What security measures should i take on front-end or backend to make my api secure?

Comment: I have never used refresh tokens, however maybe you will find this useful: https://auth0.com/blog/refresh-tokens-what-are-they-and-when-to-use-them/

Generally I use Redis to store sessions so that my server retains the capability of signing anyone out easily. But that's just a personal preference

Answer (score 0):

See this example how i secured my **getByRefId**  api  in nodejs :

In routes file :

```
router.get("/refId/:refId", helper.auth, groupController.getByRefId);

helper.auth is   function  :

auth: (req, res, next) => {
    var token = req.body.token || req.headers['authorization'] || req.headers['Authorization'];

    if (token.startsWith('Bearer ')) {
        // Remove Bearer from string
        token = token.slice(7, token.length).trimLeft();
    }

    if (token) {
        jwt.verify(token, 'MY_SECRET', function (err, decoded) {
            if (err) {
                console.error('JWT Verification Error', err);
                return res.status(403).send(err);
            } else {
                req.payload = decoded;
                return next();
            }
        });
    } else {
        res.status(403).send('Token not provided');
    }
}
```

This use  **jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')** library you can install it in nodejs project

Comment: my question is how to make my tokens save on client side